# What is Google Application Credential?

Tags: android, api, google-speech-api

I am using Google Speech API in My Android application and I am taking reference with the [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech) provided by Google in docs.

In this sample, there are several lines for the authentication process in App level gradle file.

```
task copySecretKey(type: Copy) {
def File secretKey = file "$System.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
from secretKey.getParent()
include secretKey.getName()
into 'src/main/res/raw'
rename secretKey.getName(), "credential.json"}
preBuild.dependsOn(copySecretKey)
```

In this code, I am not getting what is GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and where I should paste my JSON.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

file is the location of your json file.   they are just showing you how to use the system variable assuming you have that set to the location of said fule